# How to enable "techproducts" out of the box example on solr 6.4 version

Tags: solr

I want to enable "techproducts" OOTB example in solr 6.4.
Could you please let me know the steps to enable it?

The below does not work.
http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/browse

How to make  \example\techproducts OOTB work ?

Comment: I got it working by doing the below:

Comment: $ bin/solr create -c techproducts -d sample_techproducts_configs
$ bin/post -c techproducts example/exampledocs/*.xml

Comment: Remember that `*.xml` is expanded by the shell, so if you're running in docker etc, it won't be expanded. Give the xml file name explicitly, or get a running shell inside your container first and use that.